# Jsonpath how to select this json with inner json node

Tags: jsonpath, json-path-expression

Jsonpath is new for me and I am leaning this. I can only select the `name` as $.name. I don't know how to select `employeename` and `type` from this json? Could someone tell me how?

```
{

"name": "{\r\n  \"employeename\": \"Test  name\"\r\n}\r\n",

" availability": {

    "available": true,

    "type": "private"

},

"is_available": true
}
```

Comment: Value of key `name` is string, not json object, you can't use jsonpath to extract `employeename`. You have to covert this string `"{\r\n  \"employeename\": \"Test  name\"\r\n}\r\n"` to json object first, then extract data later.

Comment: Just tried https://jsonlint.com/ and it is Valid JSON.

Comment: Please re-read my comment, I didn't say your json is not valid, I said "Value of key `name` is string, not json object" --> can use jsonpath for this.

Comment: Yes if I do $.name I get `\r\n  \"employeename\": \"Test  name\"\r\n`. But i want select only `employeename` and try to get value as `Test name`

Comment: As I said, you have to convert this string to json object first, then extract it. What language do you use?

Comment: I am using Java 8 and in the Junit test as:- `givenValidRequest(Country.SWEDEN, Language.SE)
        .when()
        .get(vaseUrl + "/book/empolyee")
        .then()
        .log().everything()
        .statusCode(HttpStatus.OK.value())
        .contentType(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON_VALUE)
        .body("name", is(\\r\\n  \\\employeename\\\": \\\"Test name\\\\\r\\n)) // error.`
How can do it?

Comment: Junit assertion error `java.lang.AssertionError: 1 expectation failed.

JSON path name doesn't match.

Expected: is \\r\\n  \\\employeename\\\": \\\"test Name\\\\\r\\n

  Actual: {

  "employeename": "test Name"

}`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This code would be:

```
@Test
void SO_69565621() throws JsonProcessingException {
    String text = "{\n" +
            "  \"name\": \"{\\r\\n  \\\"employeename\\\": \\\"Test  name\\\"\\r\\n}\\r\\n\",\n" +
            "  \" availability\": {\n" +
            "    \"available\": true,\n" +
            "    \"type\": \"private\"\n" +
            "  },\n" +
            "  \"is_available\": true\n" +
            "}";
    String name = JsonPath.read(text, "$.name");
    JsonNode jsonNode = new ObjectMapper().readTree(name);
    MatcherAssert.assertThat(jsonNode.get("employeename").asText(), Matchers.is("Test  name"));
}
```

I'm using Jackson to convert String to JsonNode, then get value of this JsonNode.

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>com.fasterxml.jackson.core</groupId>
    <artifactId>jackson-databind</artifactId>
    <version>2.12.4</version>
</dependency>
```